# NordVPN Setup using Settings & Network Manager

Tags: networking, vpn

I have installed NordVPN on 18.04 LTS, however, I cannot enable it under network settings. I know it is running in the background as I get messages concerning my IP addresses. It installed and is working fine on Android.

I did try installing AVG VPN under Wine, but it did not work and I need to uninstall it

Comment: If you know it is running, how did you start it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and use

```
nordvpn connect
```

to connect, and

```
nordvpn disconnect
```

to disconnect.

Comment: I have run nordvpn connect but no joy